# How would I generate mipmaps for a 3D texture in Unity (at runtime)?

Tags: unity, c#, hlsl, mipmaps, raymarching

I have been trying to create a voxel cone tracer for Unity (in Universal Render Pipeline 16).

I have this *(unoptimized)* C# code that turns the [CubeScale] area around 0,0,0 of the scene into a 3D texture and saves it in the editor.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;



public class LBTraceArea : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public Texture3D Volume;
    public float CubeScale;
    public int CubeQuality;
    public string SaveAs;
    
    //pre-define texel size so it can be used among all functions
    float texelSize = 1f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {   
        Debug.Log(Volume.mipmapCount);
        //define the size of 1 3d texel/volumetric cube pixel/voxel
        texelSize = CubeScale / CubeQuality;
        VoxelizeArea();
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(Volume, "Assets/" + SaveAs + ".asset");
        Debug.Log(Volume.mipmapCount);
    }
    
    //function to create 3D texture AKA voxel image with scene objects.
    void VoxelizeArea(){


        //Setup a 3d Texture
        
        //Format
        TextureFormat form = TextureFormat.RGBA32;
        TextureWrapMode wrap = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        
        //Defining the Volume
        Volume = new Texture3D(CubeQuality, CubeQuality, CubeQuality, form, false);
        Volume.wrapMode = wrap;
        Volume.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;

        //Create a volumetric color array.
        Color[] color = new Color[CubeQuality * CubeQuality * CubeQuality];


        //Loop to actually create the color volume
        
        //Define how offset the position of the object is from the center of the Volume.
        //object Offset
        Vector3 oOff = new Vector3(
            transform.position.x + (CubeScale * -0.5f),
            transform.position.x + (CubeScale * -0.5f),
            transform.position.x + (CubeScale * -0.5f)
        );

        //define "Real Tick"/rt or how many loops total of all 3 for loops
        int rt = 0;

        //tx ty and tz is a pun because they are short for texel+(the axis, for example x) and also short for tick+(the axis, for example y)
        for (int tx = 0; tx < CubeQuality; tx++){
            for (int ty = 0; ty < CubeQuality; ty++){
                for (int tz = 0; tz < CubeQuality; tz++){
                    //tick area, ya have access to tx, ty, and tz all in here so you shouldn't need to be outsize of this when calculating coor math and stuff.

                    //Color at Real Tick AKA rt would define the exact pixel at the exact position.
                    //so Color[rt] would be Color at the pixel
                    
                    //color[rt] = new Color(tx, 1f, tz, ty);
                    color[rt] = GetColorAtPosition(new Vector3(tz * texelSize, ty * texelSize, tx * texelSize) + oOff);
                    
                    rt++;
                }
            }
        }

        //Put the colors on the 3d bitmap volume and apply the changes so it gets resent to the GPU.
        Volume.SetPixels(color);
        Volume.Apply();

    }
    
    //function to get an objects surface color at an exact Vector3 location
    void GetColorAt(Vector3 cpos){

    }

    Color GetColorAtPosition(Vector3 position) {
        Vector4 grabber = Vector4.zero;
        grabber += GetColorAtPosAndRot(position, Vector3.up);
        grabber += GetColorAtPosAndRot(position, -Vector3.up);
        grabber += GetColorAtPosAndRot(position, Vector3.right);
        grabber += GetColorAtPosAndRot(position, -Vector3.right);
        grabber += GetColorAtPosAndRot(position, Vector3.forward);
        grabber += GetColorAtPosAndRot(position, -Vector3.forward);
        return grabber;
    }

    Vector4 GetColorAtPosAndRot(Vector3 position, Vector3 normal){
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(position, normal, out hit, texelSize)){
            Renderer renderer = hit.collider.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            
            if (renderer != null){
                Texture2D texture = renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
                
                if (texture){
                    Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
                    pixelUV.x *= texture.width;
                    pixelUV.y *= texture.height;

                    return texture.GetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y);
                } else {
                    return renderer.material.color;
                }
            }
            return new Vector4(1f,1f,1f,1f);
        }
        
        return new Vector4(0f,0f,0f,0f);
    }
}
```

[image: Image of 3D Texture Volume]

*Please ignore the name of the texture. It does not currently have LODs or Mipmaps, it needs to have them which is why it is called that.*

The Debug.Log used at the end of void Start() returns with 1. which makes me believe there are no mipmaps.

I also have a custom HLSL function in the shader editor to ray march the 3D texture. The desired results are for clean and noise-free global illumination. This may not be that useful for solving the problem, but it demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish. Here is the code for that.

```
Color = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
Distance = 0;

float MarchSize = 1 / VolumeQuality;

float3 pos = float3(0,0,0);

//Define t and start 4 steps out
//4 because honestly it's the best I could do
float t = MarchSize * 4;
while (t < 1) {
    


    if (Color.a < 1) {
        pos = Position + (Normal * t);
        Color += SAMPLE_TEXTURE3D_LOD(Volume, Sampler, pos, Roughness * t);
        Distance = t;
    }
    
    //advance tick size
    t += MarchSize;     
}
Color.a = min(Color.a, 1.0);
```

Here is what this raymarch looks like in a scene:
[image: No LOD Raymarch]

Here is what it SHOULD look like (except this image has a lot of noise because I had to stochastically sample this instead of sampling it with the mipmaps):
[image: Stochastically Sampled instead of LOD]

I need mipmaps for my Texture3D, otherwise, LOD on the SAMPLE_TEXTURE3D_LOD in my HLSL(the fourth parameter of that function) does not do anything. This is bad because if I cannot obtain Mipmaps on my 3D Texture, I cannot get my desired lack of noise, and I would have to resort to using stochastic sampling or giving up. So, I need to know how to generate mipmaps for my 3D Texture.

Additional information: The 3D texture is only saved to the assetdatabase for now. I will later find a way to automatically apply the 3D texture to all raymarching shaders. I need to do this because (after I optimize my script that writes the scene to a 3D texture) I need to write the scene to a 3D texture in real time for some epic reflections and real-time GI. I say this to say that it would be ideal that the mipmapping method would be fast and work at runtime. Also, even though it may not be practical, I would prefer if the solution were to work on most URP-supported hardware if at all possible, so please no Direct-X-only stuff unless it is required.

If someone believes the issue is something else, that information would be greatly appreciated aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. Unity will automatically generate mipmaps if the fourth parameter of:

```
Volume = new Texture3D(CubeQuality, CubeQuality, CubeQuality, form, false);
```

is set to true.

So like this:

```
Volume = new Texture3D(CubeQuality, CubeQuality, CubeQuality, form, true);
```